# run bat in each subfolder from bat file

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

There are subfolders contain batch file (mp3.bat) with this code

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
chcp 65001
ffmpeg -version
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo "ffmpeg not found"
  @pause
  exit
)
SET "filename=XXX - YYY"
echo "filename: %filename%"
echo "cd: %cd%"
dir
@pause
(FOR /R %%i IN (*.ts) DO @echo file 's/%%~nxi') > list.txt
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -loglevel panic -i list.txt -c:a copy -vn "%filename%.mp3"
del "list.txt"
echo "success"
@pause
```

How can execute each mp3.bat with one batch file from parent directory?

```
for /r "." %%a in (mp3.bat) do call "%%a"
```

it doesnt work

Comment: Changing your question after you've received answers is inappropriate, as it invalidates the answers you've received. It can even make those answers wrong, and adversely affect the reputation of those who answered. If you now have a new or additional question, create a new post and ask it there; you can link back to this one if needed for reference.

Comment: sorry David, but i haven't changed my question. If you mean Io-oI's answer so i suggest he answered on "How can execute each mp3.bat with one batch file from parent directory?", but he didn't review code of batch file itself (mp3.bat). Thanks him anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should run each batch file in the sub-folders at a time:

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /s /b mp3.bat') do start /wait "" "%%a"
```

or

```
for /r %%a in (*mp3.bat) do call "%%a"
```

**Using a main batch file instead of mp3.bat in each folder:**

You have to drag and drop the main folder (where the sub-folders) are to this batch file:

```
@echo off
chcp 65001 >nul

:: Please drag and drop the main folder where sub-folders are to this batch file
:Retry
if exist "%~1" (if not exist "%~1\" (set /p "Source=Please input source folder: ") else (set Source=%~1)) else (set /p "Source=Please input source folder: ")

if not exist "%Source%" goto :Retry

cd "%~dp0"

ffmpeg -version
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo "ffmpeg not found"
  @pause
  exit
)

if exist "list.txt" del /q "list.txt"
cd "%Source%"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad *.*') do call :CreateMP3 "%%~dpnxa"
exit

:CreateMP3
cls
echo.
echo  Processing Folder: %~nx1
pushd "%~1\s"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "*.ts"') do echo file '%%~a'>>"list.txt"
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -loglevel panic -i "list.txt" -y -c:a copy -vn "%~nx1.mp3"    
del /q "list.txt"
echo "success"
popd
goto :EOF
```

**A version to place in the main folder and just double click:**

I added something to detect if the mp3 file already exists in each folder and if yes it doesn't recreate it saving time...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
chcp 65001 >nul

ffmpeg -version 1>nul 2>nul
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo "ffmpeg not found"
  @pause
  exit
)

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad *.*') do call :CreateMP3 "%%~dpnxa"
exit

:CreateMP3
cls
echo.
echo  Processing Folder: %~nx1
pushd "%~1\s"
if exist "list.txt" del /q "lista.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b "*.ts"') do echo file '%%~a'>>"list.txt"
if not exist "%~nx1.mp3" ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -loglevel panic -i "list.txt" -y -c:a copy -vn "%~nx1.mp3"    
del /q "list.txt"
echo "success"
popd
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137719/discussion-on-answer-by-ricardo-bohner-run-bat-in-each-subfolder-from-bat-file).

Comment: folders with special characters (' single quote and ! mark) in the path aren't processed

Comment: I think I got it now can you see updated answer, I think the error was with the list.txt file cause of excess of (') ex: file 'filename'filename'.....

Comment: now works correctly. nice. big thx. learn cmd with u.  Ricardo, some questions: how can run this bat with argument "current folder" instead input or drag'n'drop argument?

Comment: and 2nd: is it possible to place to general folder such bat and run it just with double click? what should change in code?

Comment: Using current path is the default you don't have to specify nothing if you want to run stuff in the current folder. Please see updated answer...

Comment: that's works. thx!

Answer (score 1):

```py
for /d /r %%i in (*)do pushd "%%~fi" && call mp3.bat & popd
```

---

You can use a **`for /d /r`** loop, which will go through all the folders, and in each folder inside the loop, use the **`pushd`** command followed by the **`call`** to run your **`mp3bat`** in the current folder and once it's done the bat, run the **`popd`**

- ```py
  FOR /R - Loop through files (recursively)
  FOR /D - Loop through several folders/directories
  ```
- ```py
  The option /D /R is undocumented, but can be a useful combination,
  while it will recurse through all subfolders the wildcard will only
  match against Folder/Directory names (not filenames)
  Note: Source linked to ss64.com
  ```

---

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Call /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- [`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [`For /R /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)
- [`For /D /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)
- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [`Goto :Label` | `Call :Label`](https://ss64.com/nt/goto.html)
- [DelayedExpansion (Refer: `!Expand_RunTime_Variable!`)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: This is another question... sorry... your code have more to review/edit, but this will change too much the actual question...

Comment: Io-oI, thank u for your answer, but there is another trouble:  mp3.bat (each subfolder contain batch & *.ts) can't full execute because code  <<  echo "cd: %cd%" >> returns to parent directory but *.ts contains in subfolders   and i dont know how prevent it

Comment: It doesn't suit and it violates the rules to change the question, what you quote substantially changes the original question, I recommend that you open a new question.

Comment: i dont know about you and which rules do i violate
i pointed at << echo "cd: %cd%" >> cause this string from code of batch file that was in the post from beginning.
Thank you anyway

Comment: Who to run bat and why bat don’t works is 2 different thing...

Comment: no man -> source bat works. it doesn't work when running source bats (subfolders contain mp3.bat) with one another bat.

Comment: yes -> 
how to run a bat in each subfolder is different from how to make bat work in each subfolder